# Facebook open graph og:image issue (empty image at facebook share)

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I am stuck with this and looking for fresh ideas. I am helping a friend blog, with blogger.com platform. Problem: the Facebook share of the blog is providing either empty image, or a corrupted image of "pencil" icon.

I tried the following:

1. reading the best practices at developer Facebook site
2. verified image is at the recommended size (600x314)
3. defined the meta tags of width and hight.
4. used the Facebook debugger tool to fetch new **scraper** data - always gets the same error:

   > og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image ... will be used instead. Consult...for more troubleshooting tips.
5. by the way, in the Facebook debugger tool, I see that the "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties" section, has indeed showed for the og:image the correct image, but it shows a thumbnail of it twice, in a layered way.

This is the code (placed within the `<head>..</head>` section):

```html
<!-- Added by Gadi to support default image for blog sharing -->
<meta property="og:title" content="BLOG HORUT" />   
<meta property="og:image" content="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rk2zwtg7_Vc/VuR2Xs9G5cI/AAAAAAAAAS0/uEJWZcyZcpQZhjUrIUiAR0gsyCfgdSSfw/s1600-r/cover4.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="314" />
```

Comment: The OpenGraph debug tool is quite confusing. The 2 thumbnails are ok, I have experienced the same. Facebook has a long caching time - usually using the debug tool should clear the cache, but often it doesn't. It might well be that FB shows your image correctly in some hours.

Comment: Sadly - it does not seems to be updated, and it has been over 72 hours since the change...

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with a server's og:image tag pointing to a secure subdomain which actually mirrors a CDN server,

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://subdomain.pathToImage.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image_secure" content="https://subdomain.pathToImage.jpg" />`

FB has a [debugging tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) which allows you to see the errors that FB encounters when trying to pull the image.

In my case the subdomain was not registered under the SSL certificate used by the HTTPS protocol.  Hence FB was getting the following error,

`Curl Error : SSL_CACERT SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following: 
Save your image again, but with new dimensions: 1200 * 628.
I am not sure where Facebook has its treshold (certainly not 200x200px as they say) - but in my project 470*246 Pixels was not enough to have Facebook accept it as og:image source. 
The og:image:*** attributes are useless imho - better remove them.